# is there possibility to connect asp.net website hosted on a different server to a database on another server?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, cookies, phpmyadmin, database-connection

I know quite ok that is is not a good idea except for inevitable reasons. it is ideal to host database on the same server with the web applications. However my server couldn't log phpmyadmin using MySQL 5 despite all credentials correctly provided with no error except for the note that "Cookies must be enabled past this point." and i have set cookies to allow, add the website and others configuration and still not working. i have tried several browsers both on PC and mobile phones and its not working either. i tried to create database from several online remote source as FreeSQl, FreeDB, Somee etc, it works fine while tesing through visual studio locally on pc remotely but as soon as i host, it will not work as a result of connection issue which am aware of. i hope someone will help me out, possible provide me with link of where i can create and setup MySql database and the connection will work live on another server where i host my website or How to solve the Phpmyadmin issue. I will fine with it. I am available to answer questions so as to help me achieve my aim. Thanks

Comment: It is possible to host the database and websites on different servers. But usually only when you have control of both servers. Shared hosters will block SQL ports in the firewall.

Comment: Do you have idea of database host or source only that is fully remote access even on a live server? if you do, share with me.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is this possible, but is a common setup. You will often have some database server system - and it certainly not going to host the web site.  The web site is VERY often hosted and placed on a different server.

In fact, some companies will adopt a hosting company for their web site, but it hits and connects to their database server that is on premises (or so called "on-prem"). In fact this approach is often used to allow say Android phones, and other services to consume data from the company database, but that company would NEVER think of opening up ports to outside connections. (they setup a secure connection between the web hosting system and their local network - often  VPN, but it really don't matter. As such the company database server ONLY allows connections from the local network and then say a pre-defined IP address incoming from the web hosting.

So, you can adopt cloud hosted say SQL running on the Azure OS. (SQL Azure). And just like all instances of Azure? Well security can be several approaches. I mean a database hosted on Azure is RARE simply opened up to the wild internet to allow ANY one to connect. Heck, 16 years ago I tested opening up my home router to outside SQL connections. In less then 20 minutes, I began to see attempted logons to that SQl server.

There are bots that scan IP numbers + ports on the internet. So I began to see this:

```
Logon fail:  sa, password="password"
Logon fail:  sa, passowrd="123456"
etc. etc. etc.
```

So there is quote a few companies offering hosted database systems Azure, and AWS come to mind. However, they don't allow just any old one with a IP address to connect. In a lot of cases, security will be some fixed IP address (like for example the companies network or external fixed IP that their ISP provider gives them. While most consumer internet systems are not fixed IP addresses? Today even relative smaller business need and want workers to work remote. So they pay a few extra dollars per month (often only about $10, maybe $20) and now they have a fixed IP address. And from that they tend to setup and adopt a VPN based on that now fixed IP address.

The hosted SQL server? Well, it also will be setup to ONLY accept external incoming request from a known IP address - and thus those bots and IP scanners can't connect.

Now MOST low cost web hosting plans include SQL server or MySQL as part of the low cost hosting package. In that case, the connection from the web site to the database server is INTERNAL and such database systems do NOT allow or permit outside connections to the database server. So, when buying a book on Amazon.com, their web hosting system can easy connect to the database - but that is NOT a outside connection.

However, can you use that VERY low cost budget web hosting, and connect OUT to a outside database? yes, a lot of them allow this, and as noted, it not going to be a surprise that some database is being hosted say on Azure. And as noted, in this case, your web hosting software will thus connect to Azure in much the same way any other outside system connects.  So while few web hosting systems allow OUTSIDE connections to the database included with such packages? Well, a lot of them certainly allow you to reach out - and hit other web sites, other web services (maybe a weather and temp display on your site????). So reaching out as a general rule is possible - reaching in? not so much!! about 10 years ago, quite a few web hosting providers - even low cost ones DID allow external ODBC connections to the database system. However, due to security issues - most providers don't allow this. I think even GoDaddy still allows this, but if you do ask for this ability, then the database server(s) you get are different then their regular ones - again they don't want to open up security issues and that can often open up holes to other customers databases hosted on that system. But, as noted, with the rise of SQL Azure and others? We are seeing a real comeback in hosting providers now offering external connections to database systems that are seutp to allow the hosted web sites to hit those databases.

So you have to check with who ever going to provide you with the web hosting, and find out if that web hosting allows "reaching out" to other web services, or reaching out to other database servers - as I noted - this is quite common now. it just a question then does the web hosting say support a VPN to reach out, or say reaching out on a particular port + fixed IP to some database server is the nitry grity details that will vary based on your needs, or what that ISP in fact allows.

So what and who and what ports are allowed to reach out? Well, that's going to be based on what your ISP and hosting plan for the web site allows - you have to check if they allow hosted web sites to "reach out" of their web hosting plans.

Comment: Yeah you are absolutely correct because while researching, I came across azure and didn't give it a try because other listed with it didn't work for me.  I will try it to see if it the connections work from my hosting server then the problem will be solved else, I will appreciate if you can point to to MySQL host that it's connection will work from my hosting server easily. thanks